# uri_does_not_exist problem in vscode appears when I use flutter run in a container

Tags: docker, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

I want to build and run my flutter app in a docker container and still code in my VSCode editor.
But when I do this vs code doesn't autocomplete and shows many errors saying `uri_does_not_exist`

I've downloaded the image `adamantium/flutter` then I've started it using the command
`docker run -itd --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb -v "/home/ammar/Desktop/zold-flutter-client":"/zold-app" adamantium/flutter`

connected to the container using `docker exec -it container_id /bin/sh -c "[ -e /bin/bash ] && /bin/bash || /bin/sh"` and flutter run did work but vscode stopped the normal behaviour and started to show errors.

I've changed the path of flutter in my machine to be the same path in the container and this solved the problem for dart and flutter  native packages `like async and material` but the problem still there with packages I've added to yml `like HTTP`

However, it's not supposed that the host machine needs to have flutter or dart installed, I want vscode to see them in the container somehow.

The dart extension log:

```
Tue Apr 16 2019 [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] Log file started
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info] Searching for SDKs...
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /home/ammar/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /home/ammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /home/ammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /home/ammar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /usr/local/sbin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /usr/local/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /usr/sbin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /usr/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /sbin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /usr/games
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /usr/local/games
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /snap/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /home/ammar/.rvm/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /home/ammar/.rvm/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /home/ammar/Portable/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /usr/lib/dart/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /opt/flutter/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     /home/ammar/.rvm/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info] Found Flutter project at /home/ammar/zold-flutter-client/zold_wallet
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info] Searching for flutter
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Looking for flutter in:
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/zold-flutter-client/zold_wallet
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/zold-flutter-client/zold_wallet/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/sbin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/sbin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /sbin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/games
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/games/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/games
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/games/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /snap/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/Portable/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/lib/dart/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Found at:
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Found at /opt/flutter
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path /opt/flutter for flutter
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info] Searching for dart
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart in:
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/sbin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/sbin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /sbin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/games
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/games/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/games
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/games/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /snap/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/Portable/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/lib/dart/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /home/ammar/.rvm/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Found at:
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/lib/dart/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info] Following symlink: /usr/bin/dart ==> /usr/lib/dart/bin/dart
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/lib/dart
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /usr/lib/dart
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]         /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Found at /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk for dart
    [08:29:02 GMT+0200 (EET)] [General] [Info] Activating Flutter extension for Flutter project...
```

Comment: You could [enable the extension log](https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#extension) and raise an issue with it at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code and I can take a look. Out of interest, why are you trying to set it up in Docker versus just running it on your machine directly?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny I wanted to make the same environment for all developers to avoid errors that appear for some and don't for others (I face many of them from time to time)

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Thanks to your hint, I read the log (it's in the question now) and I could narrow the problem down to that I should make the environment variables of my machine refer to the installation in the container (am I right?)

Comment: It's not clear what your setup is. If VS Code is running outside the container, then Dart/Flutter need to be accessible to it. I'm not sure which bit(s) you're trying to run in the container?

That said, it sounds like a complicated setup, maybe there's a simpler way to resolve the original issues?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny all that I need is to run VSCode in the docker image, that would solve it, WDYT?

Comment: Maybe, though I don't know how simple that is, and it may cause you other problems (like not letting devs have their own settings or extensions)? I think it would be better to try and tackle the issues you had without a container. I don't know what they were, but I hope they would be simpler than this :-)